# ListTile shape property [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How ListTile shape parameter works in Flutter?

```
ListTile(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          title: Text('data'),
)
```

This piece of code not reflecting rounded border(not even any border)!

Any ideas how to make this happen and use shape property of ListTile

I have seen certain examples depicting ListTile as child for Card, Container, etc. and then it works

Then what does Shape do and how to use it in ListTile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ListTile` `shape` property is designed to round the `InkWell` effect. By applying `borderRadius`, you can only notice the ripple effect (splash color) limitation on your ListTile. The border `side: BorderSide(//....)` is not taken into account. If you anyway would like to have border on your `ListTile`, consider wrapping it in another widget, `Container` for instance, on which you'll use your border.